# Change Visibility with Timer

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to implement something quite simple, but I can figure out how to do it. And I can't find a solution online anywhere.

I'd like an image to be visible and then switch to hidden after a few seconds have elapsed. (If page is refreshed, it should be visible again for allotted time.)

Is there a way to do this easily through HTML and/or Java script?

Your help is *greatly* appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is really basic. Define your image tag (I'm giving it an id for simplicity):

```
<img id="image" src=""/>
```

Then use `setTimeout` to wait a certain amount of seconds before setting the `display` property of the image to none, i.e. hidden:

```
var image = document.getElementById("image");
setTimeout(function(){
    image.style.display = "none";
}, 3000);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/Ttvn2/1/).
The timing is in milliseconds, so 3000 = 3 seconds.